# After dataframe append I have the same amount of the rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to flatten the 3rd column which contains an array:

```
import pandas as pd
import pdb

series = []
def my_method(x):
    my_array_items = None
    if len(x['Column 3']) == 1:
        if x['Column 3'][0] == 'No Val':
            return pd.Series(dict(date = x.date, id = x.id, my_array_items=None))
        else:
            return pd.Series(dict(date = x.date, id = x.id, my_array_items=x['Column 3'][0]))
    else:
        for drug in x['Column 3'][1:]:
            series.append(pd.Series(dict(date = x.date, id = x.id, my_array_items=drug)))

        return pd.Series(dict(date = x.date, id = x.id, my_array_items=x['Column 3'][0]))


data = pd.read_hdf('data.h5', 'cleanuserbase')
data2 = data.apply(my_method, axis=1)

for x in series[:1000]: # just for making it faster
    data2.append(x, ignore_index=True)
```

However, after the "for" `data2.id.count() == data.id.count()` and `data['Column 3'].count() == data2.my_array_items.count()` and

```
print data
.....
[12345 rows x 3 columns]
```

which is the same as

```
print data2
.....
[12345 rows x 3 columns]
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

The pandas `DataFrame.append` method *returns* a new DataFrame. It does not
modify the original. Therefore, you would need

```
for x in series[:1000]: 
    data2 = data2.append(x, ignore_index=True)
```

However, this would be terrible slow, since each time `append` is called a new DataFrame must be created and all the data from `data2` and `x` would need to be *copied* into the new DataFrame. That's on the order of `n**2` copies being made where `n` is the number of calls to `append`.

A faster way to achieve the same result is

```
data2 = pd.concat([data2, pd.DataFrame(series)])
```

For example,

```
In [114]: series = [pd.Series([1,2,3])]*2

In [115]: data2 = pd.DataFrame([[10,20,30],[40,50,60]])

In [116]: data2
Out[116]: 
    0   1   2
0  10  20  30
1  40  50  60

In [117]: data2 = pd.concat([data2, pd.DataFrame(series)])

In [118]: data2
Out[118]: 
    0   1   2
0  10  20  30
1  40  50  60
0   1   2   3
1   1   2   3
```

Comment: `data2 = pd.concat([data2, pd.DataFrame(series)])
` - in the loop?

Comment: Number one rule of programming: Try first, ask later. Therefore, try it in a loop and see what happens. If it works, you have your answer. If it doesn't, again you have your answer.

Comment: The rule number two: strive to avoid doing the things you don't really have to do. Your code from the 1st solution doesn't work, the 2nd does.